# how can i make {0} and {1} variables in python?

Tags: python

in C# it was Possible to Use a Code Like This:

```
Console.WriteLine ("hello{0}" ,Hello);
```

i Want to do Same Thing in Python,i Want to Call Variable With {0} and {1} Way.
How Can I Do This ?

Comment: Please put more effort into your work before asking a question. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `str.format` function:

```
"Hello {0} {1}".format(firstname, lastname)
```

You can also leave the space in between the `{}` blank to automatically pick the next argument:

```
>>> "{}, {}".format("one", "two")
one, two
```

You can also use a prettier "f string" syntax since python 3.6:

```
f"Hello{Hello}"
```

The variable inside the `{}` will be looked up and placed inside the code.

Comment: care to explain the downvote? On both of these answers?

Comment: and what if i want to use more variables like {0} {1} {2} {3}.

Comment: I've shown you this in the second snippet, simply add more arguments to format

Comment: @Makaveli You can. When each argument to format is used only once, and in left-to-write order, you can omit numbers from the placeholders. (That is, `format` has an algorithm for inferring the next number to use with `{}`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format` for the same

```
"hello {0}".format("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use place holders to format strings in Python. So in this example, if you want to use a place holder such as {0}, you have to use a method called .format in Python. Below is a mini example.

```
name = input('Please enter your name: ')

with open('random_sample.txt', 'w') as sample:
      sample.write('Hello {0}'.format(name))
```

As you can see, I ask the user for a name and then store that name in a variable. In my string that I write to a txt file, I use the place holder, and outside of the string I use the .format method. The argument that you enter will be the variable that you want to use.

if you want to add another variable {1} you would do this:

```
 sample.write('Hello {0}. You want a {1}').format(name, other_variable))
```

so whenever you use a placeholder like this in Python, use the .format() method. You will have to do additional research on it because this is just a mini example.